# Memory leakage in java

Tags: netbeans

My project is POS(Point of sale) online food delivery system on Javafx.I used Jdbc connector and not used FXML.After ordering food the heap memory becomes 1GB within 10 minutes.If we order for some time then it is continuously increasing.How to resolve this problem?

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Comment: there is no problem in coding.my project is running well but if we take large orders for food for some hours ,then it takes more memory.that means it hangs.

Comment: We want it works for 8-10 hours for food orders without being system hangged.plz give solutions.

Answer (score 2):

You very likely have a memory leak somewhere in your code. You can try to use the `jvisualvm` profiler to monitor your memory and try to find which instances are not garbage collected and remain in memory.

Comment: We have done with Netbeans profiler and not found where is the memory leakage problem?explain

Comment: Do you have out of memory error ? How much memory do you give to the JVM ?

Comment: When you monitor instances with the profiler, is there instance counts that increase constantly ?